# Time moving faster sometimes in Dying Light coop, why? When?

Tags: dying-light

We've noticed that sometimes when playing Dying Light in coop on Xbox One, time is moving a lot faster than it does normally or in single player.

Does anyone know what pattern this follows?

We thought it was just because we were in coop but then later the time moved normally again.

When it is moving faster we can literally count one-onethousand, two-onethousand, three-onethousand (ie. 3 seconds) and it moves one minute.

Comment: Were you on a particular quest? I've noticed that sometimes being on a quest (esp a main one) will cause time to go faster if a certain event is being waited for.

Comment: I can't say that I remember that either way, we have decided that for now we'll just make a note when we notice this to look more closely at where we are both on the map and in the questlines to see if there's a connection.

Comment: Like @TimS. said, certain quests do progress the game time faster because it can add difficultly with the night, or the night triggers certain events. The very first instance you can see this happen is one of the very first quests when you're out and about learning the ropes and suddenly your character looks up and it is nearly pitch black for the first time. (Like multiple game hours pass suddenly, it's just a thing dying light does, not coop specific).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several quests can accelerate or halt the speed of in-game time, all of the prologue quests up-to the first encounter with a Volatile at night will have the day/night cycle advance based on milestones rather than minutes:

Seeing the airdrop, opening the empty airdrop, the first encounter with Rais' goons and burning the Antizin. Time progression will halt or accelerate based on proximity to the the next stage of the quest.

Likewise, the first time entering Old Town will consistently start at dusk, as will the destruction of the apartment and the

> kidnapping of Jade

During the events of these quests time may accelerate to meet the requirements of these quests, and that may be what you're seeing. I don't think any of the side quests force the time of day to change, but about one third to one half of the main quests will.

Other reasons time may change include an attack from the monster in Be The Zombie, which will always, instantly, set the time to midnight (+/- one hour). This is too abrupt for what you're referring to, though.

Lastly, joining a Co-op game will set you time to your host's time. It's possible that your time was similar enough to the host's time that it looked like natural temporal progression than the instantaneous jump it actually is.